# Task Scheduler in Windows 10 throwing (0x1) on successfully completed task

Tags: cmd, robocopy

Running Windows 10 Pro I have the following command line as a scheduled task in Task Scheduler, running as SYSTEM, Run whether user is logged on or not, Run with highest privileges, configured for Windows 10:

```
Robocopy.exe V:\Users\bbearren\Documents A:\OneDrive\Documents /MIR /XJD /R:1 /W:1 /MT:64 /V /NP /LOG:V:\Users\bbearren\Desktop\RoboCopy.log
```

If I edit the trigger to run a couple of minutes in the future and then exit Task Scheduler, the task runs, writes the log, and with Last Run Result

> "The operation completed successfully. (0x0)"

If I reopen Task Scheduler and edit the trigger time to 3:00 AM (when I am logged off), the task runs successfully at 3:00 AM, writes the log file to the desktop, but shows `0x1` as the last run result.

The log results begin:

[Robocopy Log.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k1H9.png)

followed by a verbose log showing "same" files and "newer" files.  The target directory shows that the "newer" files have been written.

I don't understand what is triggering the Last Run Result of `0x1`.

My purpose for this task is to trigger an automated OneDrive sync, and this is being accomplished.

Comment: Is the robocopy command being launched from a batch/cmd script?  if not, does putting it into a .bat change what happens?

Comment: This is not intuitive, but `robocopy` returns `1` to mean 'all files copied successfully'. See [Return codes that are used by the Robocopy utility in Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954404).

Answer (score 0):

We've had some odd issues with return codes on newer OSes running scheduled batch/cmd scripts.  This worked for us.

```
Robocopy.exe V:\Users\bbearren\Documents A:\OneDrive\Documents /MIR /XJD /R:1 /W:1 /MT:64 /V /NP /LOG:V:\Users\bbearren\Desktop\RoboCopy.log

:: explicitly call exit with the errorlevel number
exit %errorlevel%
```

I know we shouldn't have to do this but we've found that in some cases it is the only way we could get the correct code out to the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue today and I found the following form
[robocopy task scheduler - last run result 0x1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0832b81-6a72-4e46-bf70-3b4eac98c95b/robocopy-task-scheduler-last-run-result-0x1?forum=winservergen)

s.roe clarified

> 0x1 is the return code of robocopy which says "OKCOPY" and is given
>   when new files in destination folder getting created. So this is no
>   error, but most services interpret 0 as no error and return code >0 is
>   an error.